# Package manager console not showing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

The package manager console in my visual studio 2022 is no longer showing. It used to show but suddenly it stopped coming up. Kindly enlighten me on how to make sure it come up when I need it .

I went through Tools - Manage package Manager - Package Manager Console but it's not coming up

Comment: Obviously we can't see your screen but *for me* when this happens, it is simply mislocated - perhaps due to monitor changes. Try using the reset window position menu item (somewhere under "Window", I guess!)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, it is "Windows -> Reset Window Layout".

Comment: You can try to reset all settings in Tools > Import and Export settings.

Comment: See my answer, try to maximize the window or reset the layout setting. :)

Answer (score 0):

After you select Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console, even if the window cannot be seen, VS2022 should be in the "selected" state for this window.

Therefore, "Window" Settings on the top of the VS2022 will be able to control the current Package Manager Console window, please try to open the Package Manager Console and then click Window->Dock as tabbed Document, this setting will maximize the Package Manager Console window:

[image]

[image]

Or you can try to reset the layout of the VS2022 via Window->Reset Window layout:

[image]